# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing Python 3.6 Vuforia

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, base64, vuforia

I'm trying to get my targets from vuforia's API, but I can't pass the last value of the header "Authorization" which is an encoded data, the error that I'm getting is this:

Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

this is in try snippet of the code, I'm following the [vuforia's documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Using-the-VWS-API) but still, something is wrong with my code and I don't have a clue what it is

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac

import requests
from flask import Flask, request
from email.utils import formatdate
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    try:
        import http.client as http_client
    except ImportError:
        # Python 2
        import httplib as http_client
    http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log.propagate = True

    url = 'https://vws.vuforia.com/targets'
    req = requests.Request('GET', url)
    req.headers = setHeaders(req)
    resp = requests.Session().send(req.prepare())

    return resp.text


def compute_md5_hex(data):
    """Return the hex MD5 of the data"""
    h = hashlib.md5()
    h.update(data)
    return h.hexdigest()


def compute_hmac_base64(key, data):
    """Return the Base64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 using the provide key"""
    h = hmac.new(key, None, hashlib.sha1)
    h.update(data)
    return base64.b64encode(h.digest())


def setHeaders(request):
    date = formatdate(None, localtime=False, usegmt=True)
    accessKey = "ce1500fhfth429279173fd839f9d414532014a3da"
    secret_key = b"5d3fdawd7211447c35be607ae5a08ec794a09d71d"
    headers = {'Date': date, 'Authorization': "VWS " + accessKey + ":" + tmsSignature(request, secret_key)}

    return headers


def tmsSignature(request, secretKey):
    method = request.method
    contentType = ""
    hexDigest = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
    if method == "GET" or method == "POST":
        pass
        # Do nothing because the strings are already set correctly
    elif method == "POST" or method == "PUT":
        contentType = "application/json"
        # If this is a POST or PUT the request should have a request body
        hexDigest = compute_md5_hex(request)
    else:
        print("ERROR: Invalid content type passed to Sig Builder")

    # Date in the header and date used to calculate the hash must be the same
    dateValue = formatdate(None, localtime=False, usegmt=True)
    requestPath = str(request.url)
    components_to_sign = list()
    components_to_sign.append(method)
    components_to_sign.append(str(hexDigest))
    components_to_sign.append(str(contentType))
    components_to_sign.append(str(dateValue))
    components_to_sign.append(str(requestPath))
    string_to_sign = "\n".join(components_to_sign)
    shaHashed = ""
    try:
        shaHashed = compute_hmac_base64(secretKey, string_to_sign)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR ", e)
    return shaHashed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into your `hmac_base64_key` function, this particular call is the cause:

```
h.update(data)
```

Since that is the `update` function from the `hmac` library, that requires the input to be byte instead of string/unicode (check out the documentation on [hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) which refers to [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) for its `update` signature).

So it seems like the fix is simply:

```
h.update(data.encode("utf8"))  # or other encoding you want to use
```

Note that you'll need to change the return value of `compute_hmac_base64` (`shaHashed`) to string again since you're concatenating it with a string in `setHeaders`.

(I'm assuming a Python 3 code even though you have a check for Python 2 in your code by the way, since you've tagged this Python 3).